# How to avoid If let in Swift before doing a for loop

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code on Swift:

```
let items = doSomethingFuncToGetDataWithOptionalResults()
if let items = items {
    for item in items {
        // so something...
    }
}
```

Could anyone can help me to avoid `if let ...` in this case. It would be better if we could ignore `if let` in this case. I feel annoyed when writing this statements every time.

Regards,

Comment: You are looking for something like `for item in? items { ... }` which only executes when items is not nil?

Comment: @luk2302 It seems to me that the array itself is optional, not its elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, if a function returns an optional then you can use
*optional chaining* to operate on the result only if it is not `nil`.

In your case of an optional array you can use
optional chaining and `forEach()`:

```
doSomethingFuncToGetDataWithOptionalResults()?.forEach { item in
    // do something with `item` ...
}
```

The `forEach()` statement will not be executed if the function
returns `nil`.

Comment: Like your comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
if let items = doSomethingFuncToGetDataWithOptionalResults() {
    for item in items {
        // so something...
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't avoid `if let` before the `for` loop at all.

Comment: I thought OP wanted to get rid of the unnecessary `if let items = items`. Martin's answer does the trick for the loop indeed :)